# JQuery / Javascript add dates to select but exclude Sundays

Tags: javascript

I would like to add 5 dates to a select but exclude Sundays.  If a date lands on a sunday show the date for the next day.

This is what I am trying so far:

```
var startDate = "6-JUN-2017";
    startDate = new Date(startDate.replace(/-/g, "/"));
    var Dates = "",  noOfDaysToAdd = 5, count = 0;
    while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
        Dates = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        if (Dates.getDay() != 0 && Dates.getDay() != 7) {
            //    count++;
            var Day = $('<option value="' + Dates.getDay() + '">' + Dates.getDay() + '</option>');
            $('select').append(Day);
        }

    }
```

But this crashes my browser. Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: You may uncomment the count++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code nearly works. However, you need to increase count, if youre not doing so you'll have an infinite loop. And as youve said, you want to increase the Day if the Day is Sunday:

```
while (count < noOfDaysToAdd) {
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1);
    if (startDate.getDay() === 0) {
     //if sunday take next day
     startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate()+1);
    }
   //always add:
    var Day = $('<option value="' + startDate.getDay() + '">' + startDate.getDay() + '</option>');
    $('select').append(Day);
 count++;//no crashing
}
```

Also theres no need to clone startDate...

Comment: I feel so stupid! Thank you very much, I uncommented count++ and it works :) I also returned just startDate instead of startDate.getDay() so that it shows the date instead in an int :)